# Loading json file error in i18next

Tags: jquery, internationalization, translation, i18next

I have added jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/puk75c1n/

```
<p id="id001" data-i18n="first_data">first</p>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  language_complete = navigator.language.split("-");
  language = (language_complete[0]);

  i18n.init({
  lng: language, 
  resGetPath: '__lng__.json',
  fallbackLng: "es",
  }, function(){
    $("first_data").i18n();
  });
});
```

It is throwing error not found.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have the same issue as here: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/471

You need [i18nextXHRBackend](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend) or define `resources` property instead of `resGetPath`